# Is the TTL (Time To Live) of an ip packet measured in seconds or hops?

Tags: http, networking

And if it is in Hops does the router still count down in seconds?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Comment: That is a pretty narrow definition of programming. Networking often comes up.

Answer (score 1):

[Wiki "Time to live#IP packets"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#IP_packets):

> The TTL field is set by the sender of the datagram, and reduced by every router on the route to its destination.

[RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#page-30):

> Time to Live:  8 bits

> This field indicates the maximum time the datagram is allowed to
> remain in the internet system.  If this field contains the value
> zero, then the datagram must be destroyed.  This field is modified
> in internet header processing.  **The time is measured in units of
> seconds, but since every module that processes a datagram must
> decrease the TTL by at least one even if it process the datagram in
> less than a second, the TTL must be thought of only as an upper
> bound on the time a datagram may exist**.  The intention is to cause
> undeliverable datagrams to be discarded, and to bound the maximum
> datagram lifetime.

Comment: But is it set as a number of seconds to count down or hops?

Comment: Seconds, but not completely reliable.